# How to construct the matrix of Hamiltonians for a hexagonal lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, hamiltonian, crystals, matrix-elements

For part of a project I need to solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation, $\mathbf H\Psi = E\Psi$ (where $\mathbf H$ is the matrix with elements $\langle\Psi_i|H|\Psi_j\rangle$, and $\mathbf S$ is a matrix with elements $\langle \Psi_i|\Psi_j\rangle$) for different lattices. I've done this for a square lattice but I'm having trouble with the hexagonal lattice. The difficulty I'm having with this is that the matrix is different depending on which sub lattice, A or B (see image below), you start on since they different possible directions (therefore different corresponding energies) to travel in.

[image: Graphene Lattice]

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am using the tight binding approximation so unless $\Psi_i$ and $\Psi_j$ are next to each other then $\langle\Psi_i|H|\Psi_j\rangle = 0$. In terms of the image above, only $\delta$ movement is allowed. $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$ and $\delta_3$ are all different in this case.

Anyone know how to make the matrix of Hamiltonians for this lattice? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There should be two atoms per unit-cell, so that the system *is* translation-invariant. Therefore, either 1) you are for some reason considering one-atom cells, or 2) you have some misunderstanding as to how to construct the $H$ matrix (or 3) I didn't understand your question).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that this lattice isnt symetric as it is in a magnetic field. So δ1≠δ2≠δ3.

Comment: Still, there has to be translational symmetry for some (presumably bigger) unit cell. You have to identify what is the unit cell of your lattice, otherwise you cannot use TB.