# Chirality effect in graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chirality, graphene

My BS research topic is 2-D nanomaterials. Currently, I am researching different 2-D nanosheets including graphene, silicene, and other elements of group IV-A. I study the chirality effect in them. I searched many articles like https://physics.aps.org/articles/v4/79.
But I still lag behind in picturing the physical working of chirality in graphene. if anyone can help me out in understanding the physical significance of chirality in graphene?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's chiral about the Dirac points in graphene?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333203/)

Comment: yes, it helped me a lot, thanks